# Multiprocessing in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've scoured the web for any solutions to my problem, but haven't really found anything that helps me.
My problem is that I wish to speed up my program by implementing multiprocessing. The function `getSVJJPrice` is rather fast. However, the size of **K** is around 1000, making the entire code pretty slow. I therefore wonder if there's anyway to parallelize the `for` loop? The code is found below.

```
def func2min(x,S,expiry,K,r,prices,curr):
    bid = prices[:,0]
    ask = prices[:,1]

    C_omega = [0]*len(K)
    w = [0]*len(K)

    for ind, k in enumerate(K):
        w[ind] = 1/np.abs(bid[ind] - ask[ind])
        C_omega[ind] = getSVJJPrice(x[0],(x[1] + x[0]**2)/(2*x[2]),
        x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],S[ind],k,r[ind],expiry[ind],
                curr[ind])  

    right = np.sum(w * (np.subtract(C_omega, np.mean(prices,axis=1)))**2)

    print right
    #if right < 10:    
    #    print '\n \n func = ', right 

    if math.isnan(right):
        right = 1e12

    return right
```

Thanks a million to whomever looks into this!

Best regards,

Victor

Comment: Hallå @Victor! Could you please provide some information about how Numpy and multiprocessing will interact with your getSVJJPrice? Alternatively, decouple the invocation of the function from the loop (maybe by  creating two different loops) and then it will be possible to optimize a bit.

Comment: This looks like it could be banged into a [Map Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) parallel processing framework.  The answer is a sum, which is the reduce step.  The map step lists all of the weights, function parameters, and subtract parameters.  The map list is distributed among the compute nodes which reply to the central node, that performs the reduce.  A google search for "map reduce python" shows several libraries to manage this sort of thing exists.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the responses guys. Will check it out @Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `multiprocessing.Pool` might be appropriate for your case, since you are looping over each element in `K`, and `K` seems like its just a 1-D array from your code.

Basically, you first have to write a function that performs the loop, in my example `parallel_loop`, and then you have to split your problem into separate chunks, in this case, you will just split `K` into an integer number of pieces `nprocs`.

Then you can use `pool.map` to perform the loop over each chunk in parallel, and the results will be collected back in order of the chunks, which have the same order as your original `K` since we didn't rearrange anything, just performed slices. Then you just have to put all of the pieces back into `w` and `C_omega`.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallel_loop(K_chunk):
    C_omega_chunk = np.empty(len(K_chunk)
    w_chunk = np.empty(len(K_chunk))

    for ind, k in enumerate(K_chunk)
        w_chunk[ind] = 1/np.abs(bid[ind] - ask[ind])
        C_omega_chunk[ind] = getSVJJPrice(x[0],(x[1] + x[0]**2)/(2*x[2]),
        x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],S[ind],k,r[ind],expiry[ind],
                curr[ind])  

    return (w_chunk, C_omega_chunk)

def func2min(x,S,expiry,K,r,prices,curr,nprocs):
    bid = prices[:,0]
    ask = prices[:,1]

    K = np.array(K)

    K_chunks = [K[n * len(K) // nprocs : (n + 1) * len(K) // nprocs] for n in range(nprocs)]
    pool = Pool(processes=nprocs)  
    outputs = pool.map(parallel_loop, K_chunks)

    w, C_omega = (np.concatenate(var) for var in zip(*outputs))

    right = np.sum(w * (np.subtract(C_omega, np.mean(prices,axis=1)))**2)

    print right
    #if right < 10:    
    #    print '\n \n func = ', right 

    if math.isnan(right):
        right = 1e12

    return right
```

Since I don't have an example data set I can't be sure that the above example would work as-is, but I think that it should give you a general idea of how it works.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for this example code. Will look into it and post any updates as to whether I got it to work!

Comment: Hey again, work flawlessly. Managed to reduce the time consumption for the `for` loop by almost 50%. Thank you so much. For those that need to pass additional arguments, it should be added that you need to `zip` the extra arguments in the iterable.